# ERROR EN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy intentando hacer un trigger en sql, pero me da tres errores que no consigo solucionar, podéis decirme si veis algún error en este trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DL_3
BEFORE INSERT ON CONGRESOS FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  SELECT AC.id_articulo
  FROM articulos, arti_congresos
  WHERE articulos.nomcongreso = arti_congresos.nomcongreso

  IF(A.nomcongreso <>: NULL) THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, 'El articulo ya esta publicado')  END IF
  ELSE IF (id_articulo <>: arti_congresos.id_articulo AND sysdate <>: congresos.fecha_ini) 
      THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20007, 'El articulo está presentado en un congreso en la fecha actual') END IF 
END
```

Me aparece un error

> sql statement ignored

en la línea del `FROM articulos, arti_congresos`, no entiendo nada.

Comment: Prmero, el `select` no almacena ningún dato. Es decir, este select tendría sentido en una sesión SQL interactiva, o desde una aplicación. Pero dentro de un trigger, si no recoges el resultado del select, ya sea con una sentencia `into`, o en un cursor, ¿para qué lo lanzas?. Luego, eso que haces con el operador `:` debiera dar error de sintaxis. No logro ver con claridad lo que quieres, pero si es hacer validaciones con los datos que trae el registro que se está insertando, lo que debes evaluar es algo como `:new.campo`.